# using list in python if statements

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to code a function that gives the user results based on the input. So basically what my function is supposed to do is to make the user input the values for day and based on that proceed towards asking the user their name. If even one of the answers doesn't match the required value, I want my code to be display invalid entry .My code is:

```
days=[monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday]
def my_function():
    for items in days:
        day=input('what is the day')
        if input==items:
            print('okay')
            for stuff in names:
            name= input("what is your name?")
            if input==stuff:
                print('great')
            else:
                print('invalid entry')  
        else:
            print('invalid entry')
```

please be gentle as i am new to python. thanks in advance

Comment: What is the questions? Also, variable `names` is not defined.

Comment: You are comparing with the `input` function not with its result.

Answer (score 1):

```
if input==items:
```

This should be:

```
if day==items:
```

Comparing `input`, which is a **function**, to a string makes very little sense.

Smae problem with your next `if`.

Comment: hi i am getting this error where if i put in monday as the first value it seems to work( i can then put in the subsequent values and it will work), however, if i start somewhere in the middle it returns invalid entry

Answer (score 1):

You should probably refactor things so you have a reusable function to have the user choose from a list.

```
def input_choice(prompt, choices):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt)
        if response in choices:
            return response  # bail out from the infinite loop
        print("invalid entry, try one of %s" % choices)


days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

day = input_choice("what is the day?", days)
name = input("what is your name?")
print("hi %s, you chose the day %s" % (name, day))
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
if input==items:
```

with this:

```
if day == items:
```

and replace this:

```
if input==stuff:
```

with this:

```
if name == staff:
```

Comment: hi, thanks alot for your answer! can you please also tell me why my loop wont end even after the user types in something invalid?

Comment: there's also an indentation issue in your code. 

i.e. for stuff in names:
      name= input("what is your name?")

it's in same indent. However it shouldn't.

Comment: not sure whether you want this. but try this:

`
days=['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

names = ['Patrick', 'Jonathan', 'Sara', 'Maria']

def my_function():
  day = input('what is the day')
  if day in days:
    print('okay')
    user_name = input("what is your name?")
    if user_name in names:
        print('great')
    else:
        print('invalid entry')
  else:
      print('invalid entry')

my_function()
`